# fedora sed command replace special characters

Tags: linux, bash, sed

i am totally new to sed and as part of script writing i am trying to replace specific string from a fiel. I know the special characters need to be escaped using backslash but the problem is if the special character is first in the line then it is not replaced....

For e.g my file contains

```
sldgfkls $bdxcv sldflksd
```

Now if i write the below code

```
sed -i 's/\b\$bdxcv\b/abcd/' filename
```

Then the above word is not replaced....But if the file contains

```
sldgfkls a$bdxcv sldflksd
```

Now if i write the below code

```
sed -i 's/\ba\$bdxcv\b/abcd/' filename
```

Then the above word is replaced.....
Please Help me here....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly, `\b` does not consider a dollar sign to be a word character, so there is no word boundary for it to match between space and `$`.

Perhaps you want this instead:

```
sed -i 's/\(^\|[\t ]\)\$bdxcv\b/\1abcd/' filename
```

Assuming yours is GNU `sed`, see https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html which contains this definition:

> A “word” character is any letter or digit or the underscore character.

and thus not dollar sign.

Comment: Thanks.....i am using \b so that only the exact matches are replaced and not the partial matches .....is the above option doing that?? replacing exact matches only..

Comment: Yeah, it looks for a match preceded by either beginning of line or whitespace. If you need to replace after punctuation as well, just add the characters you want to the character class which currently contains tab and space.

Comment: Now my second problem is that the file format stores the file such that the last thing is lr(newline feed) and cf(Carraige return)....so that the string which i want to replace ends with it..so can i use that in the second  \b....How??

Comment: '\1` contains whatever the first set of parentheses captured. Google [backrefs](https://www.google.com/search?q=sed+back+reference)

Comment: Haven't experimented, but I believe `\b` should match between a word character and a carriage return `\r`,

Answer (score 0):

sed cannot operator on strings, only regular expressions. Trying to figure out which characters need to be escaped to disable their regexp (or sed delimiter or sed backreference) meaning to make a regexp in sed behave as if it were a string is a fool's errand, just use a tool that can operate on strings, e.g. awk.

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) if ($i == "$bdxcv") $i="abcd"} 1' file
sldgfkls abcd sldflks
```

The above uses string comparison and string assignment - no need to escape anything unless one of the strings contained the string delimiter, `"`.